# Python beautifulsoup remove self closing tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove the `br` tag from an html code by using beautifulsoup.

html eg:

```
<span class="qualification" style="font-size:14px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;">
Doctor of Philosophy ( Software Engineering ), Universiti Teknologi Petronas
<br>
Master of Science (Computer Science), Government College University Lahore
<br>
Master of Science ( Computer Science ), University of Agriculture Faisalabad
<br>
Bachelor of Science (Hons) ( Agriculture ),University of Agriculture Faisalabad
<br></span>
```

My python code:

```
 for link2 in soup.find_all('br'):
        link2.extract()
 for link2 in soup.findAll('span',{'class':'qualification'}):
        print(link2.string)
```

The problem is that the previous code only gets the first qualification.

Answer (score 1):

Because none of those `<br>`s have closing counterparts, Beautiful Soup adds them automatically thus producing the following HTML:

```
In [23]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [24]: soup.br
Out[24]: 
<br>
Master of Science (Computer Science), Government College University Lahore
<br>
Master of Science ( Computer Science ), University of Agriculture Faisalabad
<br>
Bachelor of Science (Hons) ( Agriculture ),University of Agriculture Faisalabad
<br/></br></br></br>
```

When you call `Tag.extract` on the first `<br>` tag you remove all of its descendants and strings its descendants contain:

```
In [27]: soup
Out[27]: 
<span class="qualification" style="font-size:14px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;">
Doctor of Philosophy ( Software Engineering ), Universiti Teknologi Petronas
</span>
```

It appears that you just have to extract all text from the `span` element. If that's the case, don't bother removing anything:

```
In [28]: soup.span.text
Out[28]: '\nDoctor of Philosophy ( Software Engineering ), Universiti Teknologi Petronas\n\nMaster of Science (Computer Science), Government College University Lahore\n\nMaster of Science ( Computer Science ), University of Agriculture Faisalabad\n\nBachelor of Science (Hons) ( Agriculture ),University of Agriculture Faisalabad\n'
```

The `Tag.text` property extracts all strings from the given tag.

Comment: So, if beautifulsoup automatically add the closing tags for `<br>`, can this problem be avoided by using the xhtml compliant `<br/>` ?

Comment: @HolyDanna: yes. The OP would still need to use `Tag.text` or `Tag.stripped_strings` to get the contents of `span` though.

Answer (score 0):

using unwrap should work

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for match in soup.findAll('br'):
    match.unwrap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
for link2 in soup.findAll('span',{'class':'qualification'}):
    for s in link2.stripped_strings:
        print(s)
```

It's not necessary to remove the `<br>` tags, unless you require them removed for later processing. Here `link2.stripped_strings` is a generator that yields each string in the tag, stripped of leading and trailing whitespace. The print loop can be written more succinctly as:

```
for link2 in soup.findAll('span',{'class':'qualification'}):
    print(*link2.stripped_strings, sep='\n')
```